# How to protect named mutex from opening by another process WinApi?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++

I have created named Mutex and named Event in my service process for synchronizing access to data shared between my processes but I worry about some malware users will open named event and start to signal on it. How I can protect my mutex and allow open it only applications from the list?

Comment: If some bad actor has access to write to your process memory, you've lost. Period.

Comment: But he can create a new process and open event from it, permission to write in my process not needed.

Comment: So, you've basically lost in any case. I don't see how you can protect against this.

Comment: @IInspectable what I choose to comment on is outside what you get to deside on..

Comment: Thanks, I will try to perform more research in this field and describe research results in answer

Comment: what you mean under *applications* here ? your task have no any solution

Comment: maximum which here possible set  some Trust Label in SACL for only protected processes can assess for modify. but in this case your *applications* must be protected processes

Answer (score 0):

You secure a Mutex or an Event object the same way you secure any other securable kernel object: By applying an access control list.

The topic is broad. See the following resources:

- [Access Control Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-control-model).
- [DACLs and ACEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/dacls-and-aces).

Comment: Thanks, but it not suitable for me, I try to find a way to allow access to concrete processes, maybe you know how to do it using DACL?

Comment: First sentence from the first link I posted: *"The access control model enables you to control the ability of a process to access securable objects"*. Why do you believe that this were not suitable?

Comment: You can't secure objects by *processes*, only by *users/groups*. If the bad actor is running as the same user as your processes then you are SOL. Don't use named objects that are easy to find. Use handle inheritance and IPC mechanisms to pass around shared handles between your processes.

Comment: @rem: You can secure objects by process, as long as you run the respective processes under a user account, that has the required permissions. Using unnamed objects doesn't provide any security as such. It just makes finding the objects harder.

Comment: Thank you very much, but since I did the research, Remy Lebo is right, and there is no way to do this.

Comment: There is. It just doesn't work the way you want it to work.